# Backbone.js model.get() returning 'undefined' even though I can see the attributes in console.log

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model instance, which I set another model instance on, i.e `model.set('rsvp', new App.Rsvp)`.

When I iterate over the collection to generate the list of them in the view, I get `undefined` when calling `model.rsvp.get('attending')`.

Yet when I do a `console.log(model.rsvp)` I get this:

```
Rsvp
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_moreChanges: false
_previousAttributes: Object
_setting: false
attributes: Object
    attending: true
    created_at: "2012-03-28T09:42:22-05:00"
    event_id: 20
    id: 12
    updated_at: "2012-03-28T09:42:22-05:00"
    user_id: 3
__proto__: Object
cid: "c53"
id: 12
__proto__: Rsvp
```

So it would appear that there is no issue with the object, yet the get returns undefined.

I must admit my Javascript skill is still pretty weak.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`console.log( Object )` can cheat you. It won't show you the state of the `Object` in the moment of calling `console.log`.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/fhtQp/) and open the console. You see how the `console.log` shows you the state of the `Object` at the end of the script and not in the moment of the `console.log` call.

For more reliable info call `console.log` with simpler values.

*(tested is Chrome, Firefox and Safari over OSX)*

Read this for more detailed information: [Backbone.js Empty Array Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190)

Comment: You're right.  There was a bug with a $.when call, but I didn't know that was the source of the problem because console.log looked okay.  It apparently wasn't okay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory what you are doing should work, but it's probably not a good idea to bypass attributes and store properties directly on model instances. Here's a [jsfiddle that shows it works in concept](http://jsfiddle.net/mbX4Z/). My guess is that your model instance is getting recreated from source data via `fetch` somewhere else in your code so the `model.rsvp` property disappears. That or `model` is not the same instance you think it is.

Comment: I initially tried using .set first, with the same result.  And the `console.log`s are back to back.  So it shows the instance, and then shows undefined when I try to get the attribute.  So I don't see how it would be getting reset during that period.

Answer (score 0):

`model.rsvp = foo;` (lets call this code bit #1) which is equivalently `model['rsvp'] = foo;`   is not the same as `model.set({'rsvp':foo});`   (code bit #2).  If you want to tack another model instance `foo` (or some other object or value) onto a model instance `model`, use the code bit #1 or its equivalent.  If you want to add an attribute value pair to a model instance that might eventually be permanently stored somewhere, use the code bit #2.  Likewise, you're only going to have `model.rsvp` defined if you used `model.rsvp = foo;` or `model['rsvp'] = foo;`