# Backbonejs collection length always zero

Tags: backbone.js

I have a function in collection view:

```
addAll: function() {
  console.log(this.collection);
  console.log(this.collection.length);
  console.log(this.collection.models);
  this.collection.each(this.addOne);
},
```

Why the results are:

1.

```
d
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 6
models: Array[6]
__proto__: x
```

2.
0

3.
[]

we can see the this.collection have models and length = 6 in the first result

Comment: Do your models persist on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware [console.log can cheat you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut/9912865#9912865)