# Backbone direct url access breaks collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

When a user goes to `http://example.com/#/playlist`, I want to list some songs.

It works (all songs are listed) when you first go to `http://example.com` and click on the link `<a href="#/playlist">Playlist</a>`.

But if you directly go to `http://example.com/#/playlist`, nothing is shown.

When I log the this.collection property, the collection is always the same (if you use the link, or directly access).

The only difference is that `this.collection.each( function ( song ) {} );` in the render-function below, doesn't loop when directly accessing the URL.

This is the code:

```
define(
    [
        'jQuery',
        'Underscore',
        'Backbone',
        'collections/songlist',
        'views/song'
    ],

    function ($, _, Backbone, SonglistCollection, SongView)
    {
        var PlaylistView = Backbone.View.extend({

            // properties
            el: '#content',
            tagName: 'ul',
            collection: new SonglistCollection(),

            /**
             * Initialize
             */
            initialize: function()
            {
                // load songs
                this.collection.bind( 'reset', this.render(), this );
                this.collection.fetch();
            },

            /**
             * Render
             */
            render: function ()
            {
                this.$el.html('');

                console.log(this.collection);

                this.collection.each( function ( song )
                {
                    var songItem = new SongView( { model: song } );
                    this.$el.append( songItem.el );

                }, this);
            }

        });

        return new PlaylistView;

    }
);
```

The problem occurs here, in the '*each-loop*':

```
render: function ()
                {
                    this.$el.html('');

                    console.log(this.collection);

                    this.collection.each( function ( song )
                    {
                        var songItem = new SongView( { model: song } );
                        this.$el.append( songItem.el );

                    }, this);
                }
```

**UPDATE**

This is my routing code:

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'views/start',
    'views/playlist'
],

    function ($, _, Backbone, startView, playlistView)
    {
        var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
           routes: {
               'playlist': 'playlist',

               // default
               '*actions': 'start'
           },

           start: function ()
           {
               // call render on the module we loaded via the dependency array
               // views/items/list
               startView.render();
           },

            playlist: function ()
            {
                playlistView.render();
            },

            defaultAction: function ( actions )
            {
                // no default action, let's just log what the url was
                console.log('No route:', actions)
            }
        });

        var initialize = function ()
        {
            var app_router = new AppRouter;
            Backbone.history.start();
        }

        return {
            initialize: initialize
        };
    }

);
```

Comment: Can you add your routing code?

Comment: I've edited my post with the routing code, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using underscores's each method? I think it should be something like `_.each(this.collection.models, function(sont) {//code},this);`

Comment: Yes, I've tried the Underscore method before. But it gives the same result... Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem is related to the fact that you initialize your `PlayListView` before returning it to `require.js`. Also you arbitrarily call the PlaylistView's `render` method before the collection is definitely done with fetching.

1. So when you go through `http://example.com`:

   1. require init startView
   2. require init playListView -> collection fetch start
   3. route to startView
   4. playListView fetch returns -> collection now populated
   5. click link -> render playListView correctly
2. and when you go through `http://example.com/#/playlist`:

   1. require init startView
   2. require init playListView -> collection fetch start
   3. route to playListView -> render playListView incorrectly because collection still fetching (aka there is nothing to loop)
   4. playListView fetch returns -> collection now populated

Change this line
`return new PlaylistView;`
to this
`return PlaylistView;`

and the `Router` of course should be changed as well

```
function ($, _, Backbone, startView, **PlaylistView**) // change the variable name
...
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  ...
  playlistView: null, // Add attribute for the router
  ...
  playlist: function () {
    playlistView = new PlayListView();
    // No render because you bound the render to the reset of the collection !!!
  },
  ...
}
...
```

Now you won't be initializing your PlaylistView while something necessary is still left unloaded.

Comment: it's indeed better to trigger the 'render'-function if the collection is updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you call `playlistView.render();` in the `Router` the `playlist.collection` is still not populated.

You are trusting in what the `console.log(this.collection);` is showing to you but you can't trust in `console.log()` with complex objects.

Check:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9912865/316700
- http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/2NZzQ/3/

Comment: the logged data was indeed not right. But the answer from Jakee also helped me out. Can only check one aswer, but still thanks a lot!

Comment: upvoting is also appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC pattern, the view responds to changes in the model. You have that set up in your code with:

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
```

But the problem is that you're not causing a reset that would in turn cause your view to re-render. So instead of invoking the render method in 'playlist,' change the url of the collection to the appropriate REST endpoint, then do a collection.fetch. Once you do the fetch, a 'reset' will be fired, and your render will then be invoked, properly reflecting the updated collection.