# Backbone.js Empty Array Attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I'm running into an odd issue with a Backbone.js Model where an array member is being shown as blank. It looks something like this:

```
var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        // ...
        widgets: []
    },
    addWidget: function (widget) {
        var widgets = this.get("widgets");

        widgets.push(widget);
        this.trigger("change:widgets", this, widgets);
    },
    // ...
    // I have a method on the model to grabbing a member of the array
    getWidget: function (id) {
        console.log(this.attributes);
        console.log(this.attributes.widgets);

        // ...
    }
});
```

I then add a widget via `addWidget`. When trying `getWidget` the result I get (in Chrome) is this:

```
Object
    widgets: Array[1]
        0: child
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
[]
```

It's showing that widgets is not empty when logging `this.attributes` but it's shown as empty when logging `this.attributes.widgets`. Does anyone know what would cause this?

**EDIT**
I've changed the model to instantiate the widgets array in the initialization method to avoid references across multiple instances, and I started using [backbone-nested](http://afeld.github.com/backbone-nested/) with no luck.

Comment: Try `console.log(_(this.attributes).clone())` and `console.log(_(this.attributes.widgets).clone())` and see if you get different results.

Comment: Good call - it's blank when calling `console.log(_(this.attributes).clone())`

Comment: From architecture point of view I'd recommend you to use `Backbone.Collection` for widgets array.

Answer (score 23):

Be careful about trusting the console, there is often asynchronous behavior that can trip you up.

You're expecting `console.log(x)` to behave like this:

1. You call `console.log(x)`.
2. `x` is dumped to the console.
3. Execution continues on with the statement immediately following your `console.log(x)` call.

But that's not what happens, the reality is more like this:

1. You call `console.log(x)`.
2. The browser grabs a reference to `x`, and queues up the "real" `console.log` call for later.
3. Various other bits of JavaScript run (or not).
4. Later, the `console.log` call from **(2)** gets around to dumping the current state of `x` into the console but this `x` won't necessarily match the `x` as it was in **(2)**.

In your case, you're doing this:

```
console.log(this.attributes);
console.log(this.attributes.widgets);
```

So you have something like this at **(2)**:

```
         attributes.widgets
             ^         ^
             |         |
console.log -+         |
console.log -----------+
```

and then something is happening in **(3)** which effectively does `this.attributes.widgets = [...]` (i.e. changes the `attributes.widget` reference) and so, when **(4)** comes around, you have this:

```
         attributes.widgets // the new one from (3)
             ^
             |
console.log -+
console.log -----------> widgets // the original from (1)
```

This leaves you seeing two different versions of `widgets`: the new one which received something in **(3)** and the original which is empty.

When you do this:

```
console.log(_(this.attributes).clone());
console.log(_(this.attributes.widgets).clone());
```

you're grabbing copies of `this.attributes` and `this.attributes.widgets` that are attached to the `console.log` calls so **(3)** won't interfere with your references and you see sensible results in the console.

That's the answer to this:

> It's showing that widgets is not empty when logging `this.attributes` but it's shown as empty when logging `this.attributes.widgets`. Does anyone know what would cause this?

As far as the underlying problem goes, you probably have a `fetch` call somewhere and you're not taking its asynchronous behavior into account. The solution is probably to bind to an `"add"` or `"reset"` event.

Comment: awesome explanation about the tesis _"`console.log()` can cheat you"_ :)

Comment: So, how do you debug your code if you can't trust console.log?

Comment: @shim: `console.log(_(pancakes).clone())` or `console.log(model.toJSON())` are handy if you need to get a snapshot without worry about the referencing issues with `console.log`.

Comment: This answer just made my day and saved my hair from being pulled out. I owe you a beer sir.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `[]` in JS is just an alias to `new Array()`, and since objects are passed by reference, every instance of your Session model will share the same array object.  This leads to all kinds of problems, including arrays appearing to be empty.

To make this work the way you want, you need to initialize your widgets array in the constructor. This will create a unique widget array for each Session object, and should alleviate your problem:

```
var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        // ...
        widgets: false
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.set('widgets',[]);
    },
    addWidget: function (widget) {
        var widgets = this.get("widgets");

        widgets.push(widget);
        this.trigger("change:widgets", this, widgets);
    },
    // ...
    // I have a method on the model to grabbing a member of the array
    getWidget: function (id) { 
        console.log(this.attributes);
        console.log(this.attributes.widgets);
    // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see how that would become a problem, however even with a single instance of the model the issue persists. I tried instantiating the array in `initialize` anyways, but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in a fiddle with Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/XBKYZ/

```
var s = new Session;
s.addWidget({"name":"test"});
s.getWidget()
```

Console output:

```
Object
widgets: Array[1]
__proto__: Object

[
Object
name: "test"
__proto__: Object
]
```

Comment: Should probably have been more clear - I actually added something to the widgets array before trying `getWidget`.

Comment: No prob, just edit your question to reflect all the steps taken.