# Adding a model to Collection in Backbone

Tags: collections, backbone.js, model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js Empty Array Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute)

I've been working on a backbone project and came to a problem, so I mocked it up simply, but then ran into some things I didn't understand.  Here is the code:

```
(function(){
    myModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        idAttribute: 'id',
        relations: [{
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'mysubmodels',
            relatedModel: 'mySubmodel',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'mymodel',
                includeInJSON: 'id',
            },
        }],
    });
    mySubmodel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        idAttribute: 'id',
    });
    myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: myModel,
    }); 
    myView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.collection.bind('add', this.doSomething);
        },
        doSomething: function(){
            console.log('a model has been added')
        },
    });
}());

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var data = {
        id:1,
        data: 'this is one',
        mysubmodel: {
            data: 'hello'
        }           
    };

    var cltn = new myCollection();
    console.log(cltn);
    var vw = new myView({collection: cltn});

    var mdl = new myModel(data);
    cltn.add(mdl);
    console.log(cltn);
});
```

Essentially, the part that is confusing me is that the two 'console.log(cltn)' at the bottom   are both registering that a model has been added despite the fact that the model is added *after* the first log.

Comment: If you replace your `console.log(cltn)` with `console.log(cltn.toJSON())`, you should see the results you're expecting.

Comment: Yup, both of these responses were VERY helpful, the second one answers the question and the first one is a very thorough and explanation of why.  Much appreciated mu.

Comment: @mu is too short you should post your comment in answer form, both so that you can get credit and so that this question can leave the unanswered queue.

Comment: @machineghost: I'd rather let this get closed as a duplicate, I've answered this sort of question several times already :)

Comment: Fair enough; I'll add a close vote.