# Unable to get an attribute in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm writing an app in Parse.com, and I've defined an 'AppState' object which stores various constants and values which I'm passing through the app (a bit like the PHP Session).

At one point, I'm trying to read a value from the AppState object, and although it appears to be set, I'm not getting the value back.

AppState is defined by:

```
var AppState = Parse.Object.extend("AppState", {
    defaults: {
        folderShown: '',
        folderSpecial: 'all',
        showCaption: false
    }
});
```

I then have, to kick the app off:

```
var state = new AppState;
new AppRouter;
new AppView;
```

In AppRouter, I'm setting the value of "route":

```
var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "viewPage/:object_id": "viewPage",
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
    },
    viewPage:   function(object_id) {
        state.set("currentPage", object_id);
        state.set("route", "view");
    }
});
```

In App View, I have:

```
var AppView = Parse.View.extend({
  initialize:   function() {
      this.render();
  },
  render:  function() {
    console.log(state);
    console.log(state.get('route'));
  }
});
```

The first console log shows state, with the attribute 'route' set to 'view':

```
attributes: Object
  folderShown: ""
  folderSpecial: "all"
  route: "view"
  showCaption: false
```

The second console log shows 'undefined'.

If I get one of the default attributes, such as 'folderSpecial', it reads the correct value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190 help?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's just a console issue, as the subsequent behaviour is as if the value really is undefined.

Comment: You say that _In AppRouter, I'm setting the value of "route"._ -- could we please see this code?

Comment: Where do you call History.start? After new AppView?

Comment: Yes, after new AppView I have Parse.history.start();

Comment: Ok, after reading this, I moved Parse.history.start() to before new AppView, and now it's all working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes defined in routers are evaluated when `Backbone.history.start()` is called. 
From http://backbonejs.org/#Router

> During page load, after your application has finished creating all of
>   its routers, be sure to call Backbone.history.start(), or
>   Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}) to route the initial URL.

which means that your state object will only be updated when `Backbone.history.start()` is called: in your case, after your view is initialized.

Calling `Backbone.history.start` before `new AppView` should solve your problem.

A Fiddle simulating your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/LWh2P/
And a modified version : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/LWh2P/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nikoshr for tipping me off that it was to do with `Parse.history.start()`.  Moving that to before new AppView has solved the problem.