# this.collection.each doesn't iterate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to understand Backbone and tried to create some small REST API fronted, but can not get `View` to work.

`fetch()` returns valid JSON array of three elements. And `this.collection.models` is not empty (typeof `object` - `[]`) - it has tree child object elements in it. But `each` iteration doesn't fire.

When check if collection.models exists with `console.log(this.collection.models);` it looks like all is right:

[image: console.log(this.collection.models)]

I would be thankful for any advice!

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Account,
    url: 'api/v1/accounts',
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

var AccountsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {

        // Check if there is something
        console.log(this.collection.models);

        // This doesn't work
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(model) {
            console.log(model);
        });

        // Neither this
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            console.log(model);
        });
    }
});


var a = new AccountsView({collection: new AccountsCollection()});
a.render();
```

Comment: What makes you think that the AJAX `fetch` call has gotten anything from the server yet? Why don't you bind to some events on the collection instead of assuming anything about the timing of an AJAX call?

Comment: I added image from console output as argument why I think AJAX call has got something. I don't know what is best approach - if I do something wrong - just let me know.

Comment: @Orbitum That's not what he meant. The problem is that you launch the AJAX request in `initialize` and immediately attempt to use the results in `render`. Those results aren't available yet, you need to wait for them to arrive before rendering.

Comment: Ok, I understand. How can I made it to wait till results is available and only after exit from initialize function? Thank you!

Comment: And careful with trusting `console.log`, that grabs a reference which can change between when you call `console.log` and when it gets around to putting things in the console. If you're going to use `console.log` with async things, you'll want to log a copy of the data at the instance in time that matters (i.e. `console.log(some_collection.toJSON())` or similar trickery). I have some notes on this issue over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/479863

Comment: @Orbitum: I just updated my comment with a link to a relevant old answer of mine, it might be useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First option

```
var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Account,
    url: 'api/v1/accounts'
});

var AccountsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() { /**/ }
});

var collection = new AccountsCollection();
var view = new AccountsView({collection:collection});

collection.fetch().done(function () {
    // collection has been fetched
    view.render();
});
```

### Second option

```
var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Account,
    url: 'api/v1/accounts'
});

var AccountsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    render: function() { /**/ }
});

var collection = new AccountsCollection();
var view = new AccountsView({collection:collection});
```

### Third option

```
var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Account,
    url: 'api/v1/accounts',
    initialize: function () {
        this.deferred = this.fetch();
    }
});

var AccountsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.deferred.done(_.bind(this.render, this));
    },
    render: function() { /**/ }
});

var collection = new AccountsCollection();
var view = new AccountsView({collection:collection});
```

Comment: Yes, it works! But I have question - you moved fetch function outside `AccountsCollection` and now it is not so "modular". If I will extend this small code with more REST collections/models I don't think it will look good. Maybe there are more "modular" solution? Thank you!

Comment: @Orbitum: Bind your view's `render` to the appropriate events from the collection.

Comment: @Orbitum: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog and http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: @Orbitum In this case inside the collection `initialize` method save link to the result of the `fetch` method - `this.deferred = this.fetch()`. Then in the view `initialize` method - `this.collection.deferred.done(_.bind(this.render, this))`

Comment: @Orbitum Another one option - view `initialize` method: `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render)`

Comment: Yes, this works too. Now I must search which method to use. Thank you!