# Backbone collection object in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm logging one of my Backbone collections, and I'm getting this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsfBZ.png). In the object summary why does it say that the `length` is 0 and the `models` array is empty, but in the dropdown detail, gives the correct `length` and `model` array?  Also when I run `console.log(this.collection.models)` it returns an empty array just like in the summary.

Comment: Probably something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/1071630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a race condition since fetch is an asynchronous method.

Have you confirmed fetch has processed the request from the server before you call `this.model.itemList`?

To confirm this, add a console log message in the fetch method

```
user.fetch({
  success: function(response){
    user.itemlist = new itemlistcollection(response.items)
    console.log(user.itemList)
  }
});
```