# Full Object, but empty array. $.each not hitting

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, each, jquery

![information is clearly there, but not being found][1]

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to my code to make this $.each / _.each work? (I'm using both jquery and underscore, either will do)

The Array[0] concerns me. Maybe that is why the .each is getting stepped over.

**The two console.log's on either side of the each log the entire object perfectly, but when I break at the `each` and type "regionedAps" into the console, I get an empty array.**

Comment: what $.each, all I see is a huge yellow square box ?

Comment: Probably answered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/1071630

Comment: I also noticed that you named the `_.each` iterator args `(idx, val)`, which makes them sound like they are reversed.  The `_.each` iterator gets `(value, key, list)` args, in that order.

Comment: Yeah, I had to switch that around too `$.each` is reversed from `_.each`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array that you are treating like an object. You should make regionedAps an object, then `.each` will iterate over it properly.

```
var regionedAps = {};
```

I don't think you need `$.makeArray()`