# Fetching and adding models to a collection

Tags: backbone.js

```
var RippleId = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(toresolve) {
        this.url= config.rippleaccount.id.urlModel+toresolve;
        this.set('id', toresolve)
    }
});

var RippleIds = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RippleId,

    createIdList: function(toresolves) {
        var self = this;
        _.each(toresolves, function(toresolve) {

            var model = new RippleId(toresolve);
            model.fetch({
                success: function(model,response) {
                    self.add(model);
                }
            });

        });
    }
});

var toresolvelist = new rippleids();    
toresolvelist.createIdList(toresolves);
```

`toresolvelist.toJSON()` doesn't return anything (instead of the collection's objects).

I guess it's a problem of waiting that the collection has been correctly populated but I thought it was ok because I wait for model fetching success before adding it.

When I `console.log(toresolvelist)` it shows me that the result is here. But I can't access it through `.get` or `toJSON` so I guess `console.log` is cheating me.

I'm having a hard time identifying what the problem is and I can't solve it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413500/backbone-js-populating-a-collection/8415515#8415515 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781970/returning-a-backbone-collection-and-iterating-through-not-with-a-view/26782761#26782761

Comment: thanks diging into this

Comment: Actually I understand the problem but still can't solve it properly ;. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a complete list of your models, you need to wait for each of the XHR calls to resolve. This can be done with [`jquery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) on the values returned by `model.fetch` :

```
var RippleIds = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RippleId,

    createIdList: function(toresolves) {
        var self = this, xhrs = [];

        xhrs = _.map(toresolves, function(toresolve) {
            var model = new RippleId(toresolve);
            var xhr = model.fetch().then(function() {
                self.add(model);
            });
            return xhr;
        });

        // promise that will resolve when all fetches have completed
        var combined = $.when.apply(null, xhrs);

        // event triggered when all models have been instantiated
        combined.then(function() {
            self.trigger('allin');
        });

        return combined;
    }
});

var toresolvelist = new rippleids();    
var promise = toresolvelist.createIdList(toresolves);

// with an event
toresolvelist.on('allin', function() {
    console.log('get model with an event', toresolvelist.get(1));
});

// with a promise
promise.then(function() {
    console.log(toresolvelist.toJSON());
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/13mz3r3y/4/

Comment: var toresolvelist = new rippleids();    
toresolvelist.createIdList(toresolves);

Comment: The problem is that I would like access my collections from the outside
    var toresolvelist = new rippleids();    
    toresolvelist.createIdList(toresolves);
toresolvelist.get("someid") or toresolvelist.toJSON is not working

From the outside how can I be sure my collections is ready ? thanks again!

Comment: Outside the callbacks? You can't, the asynchronous nature of the operations means you have to wait, somehow, that the fetches have completed either with promises or events.

Comment: Ok but how and when can I can access models once my collection has been instanciated ?

mycollection.get("model"); doesn't work.

Comment: do I have to override the collection getter ?

Comment: `mycollection.get` does work, once the model has been added http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/13mz3r3y/4/

Comment: ok now this is obvious I just had to chain the returned promise.
You rocks I learned a lot thank you very much!

Comment: What's kinda surprising is that this solution could be included in the backbone library ... I mean this problem is really common