# Which function of a view gets executed first? initialize or render?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I inserted three `console.log` into the following code, which is from the tutorial [Your First Backbone.js App](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/04/services-chooser-backbone-js/).

My question is: why `console.log(this.el)` shows the element's innerHtml is already "rendered" but the `console.log('render runs!')` message prints after it?

Which function of the View gets executed first? initialize or render?

```
$(function(){

    // Create a model for the services
    var Service = Backbone.Model.extend({

        // Will contain three attributes.
        // These are their default values

        defaults:{
            title: 'My service',
            price: 100,
            checked: false
        },

        // Helper function for checking/unchecking a service
        toggle: function(){
            this.set('checked', !this.get('checked'));
        }
    });


    // Create a collection of services
    var ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // Will hold objects of the Service model
        model: Service,

        // Return an array only with the checked services
        getChecked: function(){
            return this.where({checked:true});
        }
    });

    // Prefill the collection with a number of services.
    var services = new ServiceList([
        new Service({ title: 'web development', price: 200}),
        new Service({ title: 'web design', price: 250}),
        new Service({ title: 'photography', price: 100}),
        new Service({ title: 'coffee drinking', price: 10})
        // Add more here
    ]);

    // This view turns a Service model into HTML
    var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',

        events:{
            'click': 'toggleService'
        },

        initialize: function(){

            // Set up event listeners. The change backbone event
            // is raised when a property changes (like the checked field)
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.el);

            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        },

        render: function(){

            // Create the HTML
            console.log("render runs!");

            this.$el.html('<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="' + this.model.get('title') + '" /> ' + this.model.get('title') + '<span>$' + this.model.get('price') + '</span>');
            this.$('input').prop('checked', this.model.get('checked'));

            // Returning the object is a good practice
            // that makes chaining possible
            return this;
        },

        toggleService: function(){
            this.model.toggle();
        }
    });

    // The main view of the application
    var App = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Base the view on an existing element
        el: $('#main'),

        initialize: function(){

            // Cache these selectors
            this.total = $('#total span');
            this.list = $('#services');


            // Listen for the change event on the collection.
            // This is equivalent to listening on every one of the 
            // service objects in the collection.
            this.listenTo(services, 'change', this.render);


            // Create views for every one of the services in the
            // collection and add them to the page

            services.each(function(service){

                var view = new ServiceView({ model: service });
                this.list.append(view.render().el);

            }, this);   // "this" is the context in the callback
        },

        render: function(){

            // Calculate the total order amount by agregating
            // the prices of only the checked elements

            var total = 0;

            _.each(services.getChecked(), function(elem){
                total += elem.get('price');
            });

            // Update the total price
            this.total.text('$'+total);

            return this;

        }

    });

    new App();

});
```

Output from the console is as follows:

```
child {cid: "view7", model: child, $el: init[1], el: div}
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="web development"> web development
<span>$200</span></div>
render runs!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialize` is always called first as it's inside the default Backbone's view constructor.

`render` is called whenever you manually call it.

```
services.each(function(service) {

    // ServiceView 'initialize' is called here.
    var view = new ServiceView({ model: service });
    // ServiceView 'render' is called here.
    this.list.append(view.render().el);

}, this);
```

## Why the console shows the `el` before rendering?

In fact, the console doesn't show the element before rendering, but it is evaluated when you check it in the console.

Here's a simple example:

```
var myObject = {};

console.log(myObject);

myObject.test = "value";
```

If you had to guess, you'd say that an empty object is logged and you wouldn't be totally wrong.

[image: Logged object being evaluated]

The little blue `!` says:

> Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was evaluated just now.

As mentioned by "mu is too short",

> the console contains [live references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/1218980) and doesn't copy anything. So when you get to the console to look at `this.el`, it shows you what `this.el` is right now rather than what it was when `console.log(this.el)` was evaluated.

Comment: but inside the initialize function, "this.el" is already rendered to contain stuff, which is produced inside the render function. this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ShawnChen check the second part of my answer which explains how the console try to help by evaluating the logged object later. At first, `this.el` only contains the empty `div` mentioned by `tagName`, but when the console re-evaluate the element, it shows its latest state.

Comment: Note that `HTMLElement` (which `this.el` is)  are objects and not strings.

Comment: @ShawnChen The console contains [live references](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/479863), it doesn't copy anything. So when you get to the console to look at `this.el`, it shows you want `this.el` is right now rather than what it was when you said `console.log(this.el)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You let me understand how console.log works. It is really helpful!

Comment: @ShawnChen It's a pleasure to help, welcome on Stack Overflow!