# Backbone.js read model attributes in initialize

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

In one of my view I need to recopy an attribute value into another attribute.

Here is the code in my code in coffeescript

```
class MyFactoryView extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->
    @model.fetch reset: true
    @model.set('NewStatus', @model.get('CurrentStatus'))
```

This code throws an undefined exception when I call get.

But if I do a console.log @model, I can see the `CurrentStatus` in attributes.

Comment: [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) is an AJAX call so you have to use one of its callbacks or an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mu said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001924/backbone-js-read-model-attributes-in-initialize#comment67285947_40001924), `fetch` is async and you only have access to the attributes once it's finished.

```
class MyFactoryView extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->
    @model.fetch 
      reset: true
      context: @
      success ->
        @model.set('NewStatus', @model.get('CurrentStatus'))
```

For that specific line, it could be simpler to use the `parse` function of the model to initialise the `NewStatus` attribute on sync.

For the console, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584864/1218980) which explains that *the console contains [live references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190) and doesn't copy anything.*