# Backbone view events binding late

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I am having problems triggering an event on the initialization of a view. If I use setTimeout to call the event, the event is fired. However the event is not fire on the view's initialization.

```
/*global app */

define([
    'handlebars',
    'text!templates/achievements.html'
], function (Handlebars, AchievementsTemplate) {
"use strict";
var AchievementsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    achievementsTemplate: Handlebars.compile(AchievementsTemplate),

    initialize: function () {
        var el = this.render(this.model);
        this.$weekFilter = $(el).find(".challenge-nav li.open a");
        this.model.bind('change', this.resetFilters, this);
        this.resetFilters();
    },
    render: function (model) {
        this.$el.html(this.achievementsTemplate(model.toJSON()));
        return this.$el;
    },
    events: {
        "click .challenge-nav li a": "filterAchievements"
    },
    resetFilters: function () {
        this.$weekFilter.first().trigger("click");
    },
    filterAchievements: function (ev) {
        console.log("test");
    }
});
return AchievementsView;
});
```

The above does not call the resetFilters function, but if I do a setTimeout, the function is called. Only guess is that the events are bound very late? Any Idea?

```
Hi All,

/*global app */

define([
    'handlebars',
    'text!templates/achievements.html'
], function (Handlebars, AchievementsTemplate) {
"use strict";
var AchievementsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    achievementsTemplate: Handlebars.compile(AchievementsTemplate),

    initialize: function () {
        var el = this.render(this.model);
        this.$weekFilter = $(el).find(".challenge-nav li.open a");
        this.model.bind('change', this.resetFilters, this);
        this.resetFilters();
    },
    render: function (model) {
        this.$el.html(this.achievementsTemplate(model.toJSON()));
        return this.$el;
    },
    events: {
        "click .challenge-nav li a": "filterAchievements"
    },
    resetFilters: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.$weekFilter.first().trigger("click");
        },100);
    },
    filterAchievements: function (ev) {
        console.log("test");
    }
});
return AchievementsView;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `resetFilters` is not been called?, try to add a `console.log` into it. I'm guessing the problem is that the `this.$weekFilter` DOM element is not completely full filled in the moment the method is called.

Comment: Ya this.resetFilters() is definitely being called. Console.logged it. The issue is that when I trigger the click event, the filterAchievements is not being called. Even console.logged(this.$weekFilter) to see if it was loaded into the DOM, and it sure was.

Comment: I still think the problem is that `this.$weekFilter` is not loaded when `self.$weekFilter.first().trigger("click");` is called. [Whatever console.log sais](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut/9912865#9912865), try `console.log( self.$weekFilter.first() )` just before `self.$weekFilter.first().trigger("click");`.

Comment: Will definitely do. Will work on it tonight and revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `$weekFilter` DOM element is not part of the Achievements template, so it is in the DOM when you `initialize` the widget, then the problem is that all events are delegated after the initialization. See backbone's source: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-145.

Why don't you move `this.resetFilters()` to `render()`?