# Backbone outputing empty array for collection.models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-relational

Having a problem where if I do

```
apples = new Apples
apples.fetch()
console.log apples
console.log apples.models
```

`console.log apples` will out put the Apples Collection, with `models: Array(10)` listed inside the object.

But, `console.log apples.models` outputs an empty array.

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to console.log the collection right after executing the fecth() method or waiting for the callback to be executed by using apples.on('reset', function(){ console.log(this.models} } ,this); ?

Comment: Not waiting; But now see this as the problem; thank you! If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to console.log the collection right after executing the fecth() method or waiting for the callback to be executed by using

```
apples.on('reset', function(){ console.log(this.models);} ,this);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked out for me. Backbone collections have a few underscore methods which work out of the box. Try using toArray to get the apple models in the apples collection.

```
  apples.toArray()
```