# The model attribute in backbone is not defined?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im using backbone to construct my client-side app, what im trying to do is is display a joke each time the user clicks .get_joke on an event: heres my backbone app code:

```
JokeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: '/jokes'
   initialize: function() {
      this.fetch();
  }
});

JokeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<p><%= joke %></p>")
    events: {
      "click .get_joke" : "render"
  } 
    render: function() {
       var newJoke = new JokeModel;
       $(this.el).html(this.template(newJoke.toJSON()));
  }
});

newJokeView = new JokeView;
```

the problem when i click .get_joke it deosnt render the joke to the view, i know the the model has been fetched because i check with console.log, but it says joke hasn't been defined, but i dont't know where the problem is. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can not trust in what `console.log` sais about a complex object:

- [Backbone.js Empty Array Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459244/backbone-js-empty-array-attribute/11463190#11463190)
- [Backbone.js model.get() returning 'undefined' even though I can see the attributes in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut)

What is happening is that the `joke.fetch()` is asynchronous and when you call `jokeView.render()` the model is still not ready.

You should modify a little bit your architecture and assigns a proper View to each Joke, so you can have for each Joke a View that is taking care of show it when is needed.

```
// code simplified an not tested
JokeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: '/jokes'
});

// This View is new and it is taking care only for the common event "click .get_joke"
// which is not related with any Joke in particular
// This View should be in charge of the JokesCollection 
// but I don't want to make things more complicate
JokeControls = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .get_joke" : "render"
  }, 

  getJoke: function(){
    var joke = new JokeModel();
    var view = new JokeView({ model: joke, el: this.$el.find( ".joke-wrapper" ) });
    joke.fetch();
  },
});


// This is the View that is related with unique Joke
JokeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<p><%= joke %></p>"),

    initialize: function(){
      // see how it shows itself when the Model is ready
      this.model.on( "change", this.render, this );
    },

    render: function() {
       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

// Activate the Joke Controls
newJokeControls = new JokeControls({ el: "#joke-controls" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
JokeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: '/jokes'
   parse : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
   }
   initialize: function() {
      this.fetch();
  }
});
```

I'd also log out the following:

```
newJoke.toJSON()
```

To see what you're actually trying to render.