# get attribute from the backbone model which is returned from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

my backbone model is :

```
var SampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

         url : "/trade/investadjustupdate")

    });
```

and i make server call as follows :

```
var investAdjustModel= new SampleModel();
investAdjustModel.fetch();
```

when i printed the model like the following : `console.log(investAdjustModel);`

and this is the screen shot of `console.log(investAdjustModel);`

[image]

i get all the value returned from th server but when i try to get a property like `investAdjustModel.get("investAdjustRow"))` it says `undefined`

so how to get the property which is returned from the server?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the response from - console.log(investAdjustModel);

Comment: @RaoulGeorge added the screen shot for `console.log(investAdjustModel);`

Comment: Could this be the issue you are facing? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch is Ajax, which is ***Asynchronous*** . So it depends where you are trying to log the object.

If you are trying to log it immediately after the fetch then it ought to be undefined.

Either use the `success callback` to log it , or listen to a `sync` event for the model to log it.

```
investAdjustModel.fetch({

    success: function() {
        console.log(investAdjustModel.get("investAdjustRow")));
        // This should work
    } 
});

console.log(investAdjustModel.get("investAdjustRow")));
// Will be undefined here
```

Comment: Yes, i have also solved this manner only, forgot to update the answer.+1